# Parametric equation in cylindral coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If you have the two surfaces $z=r$ and $r=2\cos(\theta)$, which are both in cylindrical coordinates and you want to find a parametric equation for it, how do you do it? I know how to do it in Cartesian, but I can't get the grasp of it in cylindrical coordinates.

I appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

The requested equations are, for the parameters $(z,\theta)$,

$$\begin{cases}r=z,\\\theta=\theta\end{cases}$$

and

$$\begin{cases}r=2\cos\theta,\\z=z.\end{cases}$$

The first is a double cone of revolution around the vertical axis and the second a vertical cylindre of revolution (shifted).